# How to do an action when unchecking a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Well basically I have 3 check boxes. Each of them has a boolean which gets turned to true when a button is clicked and the box is checked.

However is it possible to do an action, when unchecking a check box without having to hit another button to trigger an event first.

so as example:
    I select check box 1 & 2. =>
    I hit start button -> boolean for check box 1 & 2 gets set to true. =>
    I uncheck check box 2 -> trigger event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `onchange` attribute of the input tag which activates some javascript; eg:

HTML:

```
<input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox_id" onchange = "change()" value = "foo">
```

JavaScript:

```
function change()
{
//do something
}
```